# How do I get these SoundCloud links to work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, soundcloud

Some of the players aren't showing up.  Thoughts, suggestions?

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/do-you-know-other-wave-equations/2328#2328

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes just editing and saving fixes it, but I noticed that you have already tried that.  I copied the text into an external text editor and it doesn't look like there is any difference between the ones that work and the ones that don't.  Maybe there is a limit to how many SoundCloud links you can put in a post?

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think maybe it's a limit on the number of links as well.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: I don't know if this could be related, but make sure the sound samples you are linking to are marked 'public'. See http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled/191#191

Comment: @Robert, That was definitely the first issue I ran into [before posting the meta question]. I've got everything public now, but still no dice on the last few links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 5 Sound Cloud links could be embedded per post; we have increased that number to 10 now and made a dummy edit to the post, so everything shows up now.

Comment: Ok great, it's official.  Thanks :)

Comment: The player is still not showing up for the 3rd link (Saw tooth wave) out of 8 on that answer.  All the rest are fine.  (I'm using Firefox 7.0.1 on Windows 7)